# Корректный поворот ImageView и FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, framelayout

Имеется Imageview внутри **FrameLayout** (оба имеют **Layout_margins**),помимо этого,так же присутствует мой кастомный FrameLayout (у него кстати так же проставлен **Layout_margins**).
Другими словами,вот что есть на текущий момент:
[image: Source]
Код(.axml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:layout_weight="100"
    android:clickable="true">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/MainFrameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="80">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/SourceFrame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">
            <ImageView
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/Img"
                android:layout_margin="10dp" />
        </FrameLayout>
        <CustomFrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/CustomView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Что именно мне нужно(программно поворачивать налево\право посредством нажатия кнопки,т.е. если фотография повернута в ландшафт,то соответственно показывать ее укороченную,если вертикально,то на растянуть,типа match_parent):
[image: MyGoal]

В общем я пробовал,но почему то получается странная вещь,а именно,после поворота,к примеру,те же ImageView.getHeight()/getWidth() не изменяются,а остаются такими же,какими были и в вертикальном варианте.(но это же не правильно,тем более,относительно этих значений(высота,ширина),я считаю специальный коэффициент(ратио),по которому я буду высчитывать координаты!).
Так же мне нужно ограничить кастомный FrameLayout в размерах,т.е. чтобы при повороте,он был больше ImageView в соответствии с **Margin_layout**.

Какие либо варианты? Благодарю!

**UPD**:
что я пробовал делать:

```
    //для imageView когда поворачиваю в ландашфт
FrameLayout.LayoutParams Parametrs = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
Parameters.setMargins(10,10,10,10);
Parameters.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
imageView.setLayoutParams(Parametrs);
```

То вся ширина и длина ImageView остается прежней(то бишь,повернули в ландшафт и Width/Height должны измениться,но они остаются теми же).

Comment: Покажите код, кои поворот делаете.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавил код!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` в `ImageView`

**UPDATE**: Другие значения, принимаемые [ImageView.ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html):

- center
- centerInside
- fitCenter
- fitEnd
- fitStart
- fitXY
- matrix

Comment: проблема в том,что мне не нужно обрезать фотографию. И более того,при повороте я должен программно изменить мой FrameLayout и ImageView,чтобы они соответствовали фото. В этом и беда!

Answer (score 1):

Лучше если для каждой ориентации будет своя разметка.

Comment: дело в том,что у меня приложение строго в "Portrait" варианте,поэтому поворот и пересоздание,очень дорогостоющая операция.
Мне нужно программно менять параметры.

Answer (score 0):

Можно свою вьюху написать. Я в своё время [писал](http://suvitruf.ru/2013/12/17/3426/) об этом:

```
public class ResizableImageView extends ImageView {

    public ResizableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
         Drawable d = getDrawable();

         if(d!=null){
                 int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
                 int height = (int) Math.ceil((float) width * (float) d.getIntrinsicHeight() / (float) d.getIntrinsicWidth());
                 setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
         }else{
                 super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
         }
    }

}
```

Такое изображение будет растягивать по ширине, а потом высоту подгонять.